# How to fix 'HttpMessageNotReadableException' and 'SocketTimeOutException' occured in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, networking

I faced an `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with `SocketTimeOutException`  in production environment whose root cause I was not able to figure out and also not able to reproduce. Since it occurred in production, I want to fix this and so that clients may not face issues again. Hope the community could help.

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: (was java.net.SocketTimeoutException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.net.SocketTimeoutException) (through reference chain: com.org.example.api.request.SignatureRequest["users"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
caused by com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.net.SocketTimeoutException) (through reference chain: com.org.example.api.request.SignatureRequest["users"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]) caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

**I have tried** possible bad requests from postman hitting the API. I was able to produce `HttpMessageNotReadableException` but not `SocketTimeOutException`. We are using Spring boot 2.0.4

I wanted to figure out why this has happened and how could I possibly stop it from occurring in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For HttpMessageNotReadableException**

If you can reproduce the issue by bad request then you can handle them by applying the validation or using try-catch.

**For SocketTimeOutException**

Preventing SocketTimeoutException, One way to effectively handle it is to define a connection timeout and later handle it by using a try-catch block.

**Example:**

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000); //set the timeout in milliseconds
```

Comment: Can you tell me the root cause of this exception? Why this might have occurred?

Comment: For Socket Time Out Exception will occur when the connection is interrupted by some other process and the connection timeouts itself.
For more info on socket Time Out Exception you can google it or you can start with : [sockettimeoutexception](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/sockettimeoutexception/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-how-to-solve-sockettimeoutexception/)